Is it possible to see thermal columns?
The most common way gliders gain altitude is to circle in a thermal. Thermals are often found below cumulus clouds, or above dark areas on the ground. Without these signs, they are harder to find and require luck or experience (e.g. reacting to forces pushing the glider).
However, on Aviation.SE someone claimed:

I once had an instructor who could see thermals against the sky. His vision was acute enough, or developed to be, that he could perceive the shimmer that rising heat produces, distorting the sky behind, or if he was a loft, presumably against the more solid scenery.
Birds on average have about 10 times the number of receptors in their eyes, thus they must see the shimmer 10 times better than the best trained human.

Is this possible?
[Gliders fly slowly (80 to 200 km/h), at low altitude (below 6 km), with high glide ratio (40 to 60), and never fly into clouds.]

The refractive index of air is often taken to be one, but in fact it's slightly higher. Under normal conditions it's about $1.0003$. To a good approximation the refractive index minus one is proportional to the density of the air, and since hot air is less dense than cold air (at the same pressure) that means hot air has a very slightly lower refractive index. Every one degree change in temperature would change the refractive index by about $0.000001$.
So if we have a column of hot air in the middle of cooler air this will behave like a cylindrical lens. Since the refractive index of the hot air is only slightly less than the cooler air the lens will have a very low power, but it will slightly refract the light passing through it and it's certainly possible that if you knew what to look for you could see this refraction as a slight distortion of the landscape behind the thermal.
The change in refractive index due to temperature (or pressure) is the basis of a technique called Schlieren imaging. You may have seen images like this one of a candle:

(from the Science Photo Library)
Schlieren imaging uses an optical setup that enhances the contrast to make the refractive index changes easily visible, and the effect of the thermal would be dramatically smaller than this but potentially still visible. This change in refractive index is what causes mirages.

The question is whether the change is big enough to be visible by human eyes.

I think that's more biology than physics, but I have personally seen heat shimmer on hot days so I would not rule out an experienced pilot being able to see the distortion caused by a thermal. I'd guess the effect will be small, but if you know what to look for it may be visible.

Raptors (and possibly many other bird species) can almost certainly see thermals. Some humans may be able to see them. A related effect is astronomical seeing. Even with the naked eye, an experienced observer can tell when the seeing is bad. OTOH, (in my experience) that's an overall impression, not localised to a particular region of the sky.
